# Button with 4 values in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make one button with 4 different texts which will be toggling after clicking on it.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="changeButton()" class="button" id="button">EUR -> BTC</button>
```

JS:

```
function changeButton() {
let btn = document.getElementById("button");
if (btn.innerHTML === "EUR -> BTC") {
    btn.innerHTML = "BTC -> EUR"
} elseif (btn.innerHTML === "BTC -> EUR") {
    btn.innerHTML = "PLN -> BTC"
} else {
    btn.innerHTML = "BTC -> PLN"
}
```

}

I'm getting this:

```
index.html:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: changeButton is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:15)
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Nothing, as far as I can see. The problem is likely to either be you not having loaded your Javascript file correctly, the function being in an inner scope, or perhaps a syntax error elsewhere in the file that prevents it from running. Is there anything else showing on the console?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note:

`elseif` is not valid javascript.

You should be checking and setting `innerText`, not `innerHTML`

You can use a switch statement to make it slightly more readable/easier to manage:

```
function changeButton() {
    let btn = document.getElementById("button");
    switch (true) {
        case btn.innerText === "EUR -> BTC":
            btn.innerText = "BTC -> EUR";
            break;
        case btn.innerText === "BTC -> EUR":
            btn.innerText = "PLN -> BTC";
            break;
        case btn.innerText === "PLN -> BTC":
            btn.innerText = "EUR -> BTC";
            break;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

See example snippet below:

```js
function changeButton() {
    let btn = document.getElementById("button");
    switch (true) {
        case btn.innerText === "EUR -> BTC":
            btn.innerText = "BTC -> EUR";
            break;
        case btn.innerText === "BTC -> EUR":
            btn.innerText = "PLN -> BTC";
            break;
        case btn.innerText === "PLN -> BTC":
            btn.innerText = "EUR -> BTC";
            break;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeButton()" class="button" id="button">EUR -> BTC</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fixed code] for u. I hope that this points you in the right direction and is what you are looking for. :)

```html
<button onclick="changeButton()" class="button" id="button">EUR -> BTC</button>

<script>
    let btn = document.getElementById("button");
    let clicks = 0;

    function changeButton() {      
        if(clicks == 1)
            btn.innerText = "BTC -> EUR";
        if(clicks == 2)
            btn.innerText = "PLN -> BTC";
        if(clicks == 3)
            btn.innerText = "BTC -> PLN";
        if(clicks == 4)
            btn.innerText = "EUR -> BTC";

        console.log(clicks, btn.innerText);
        clicks++;

        if(clicks > 4)
            clicks = 1; // makes sure that the text never duplicates
        }
    }
    // 
    btn.addEventListener('click', changeButton);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. wrap your script with `DOMContentLoaded`

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

your script code not running because dom tree not ready to work before js script load

2. code review

```js
function changeButton(event) {
  const text = event.target.textContent
if ( text === "EUR -> BTC") {
  event.target.textContent = "BTC -> EUR"
} else if (text === "BTC -> EUR") {
    event.target.textContent = "PLN -> BTC"
} else {
  event.target.textContent = "BTC -> PLN"
}
```

when you try to search element like `let btn = document.getElementById("button")` browser have to search dom tree whenever you click the button. It can be better to use `event`